# How I Can convert type basicmap (ConfigurationManager) to array?

Tags: c#, app-config

I have code:

```
exampleConfigSection config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("example") as exampleConfigSection

var x = (config.Color as IEnumerable<BasicMap>).ToArray();
```

I don't have an idea how I could convert config.color to list.

Please to help me :)

Comment: post your exampleConfigSection code

Comment: Do you create a custom section? The question isn't clear because [BasicMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollectiontype(v=vs.110).aspx) is a enum type the for the type ConfigurationElementCollection

Comment: I had done section configuration. The config.Color is collection with type BasicMap.